# Is "[object Function]" uniquely for built-in functions?

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet, built-in

I am trying to write a bookmarklet that only dumps non-built-in globals to the console. I found window.Audio and some other built-in functions to have toString() return "[object Function]".

Is it possible to build functions (would it make sense?) whose .toString() return "[object Function]" without overriding .toString() In other words, is it possible I am skipping non-built-ins because I skip "[object Functions]"'s ?

This question is part of me trying to polish my bookmark : https://gist.github.com/4635185

Comment: I'm getting `"[object Audio]"`. What browser are you using?

Comment: I read your question more than twice times, and still figuring what you want. However you still can create "[object Function]" that isn't default.

Comment: Chrome Version 24.0.1312.56 m

Comment: @GabrielGartz essentially, a good web app should have a minimal of global variables, this bookmarklet would list them. Since a lot of them are built-ins I am trying to strip them out. Right now, the bookmarklet shows for stackoverflow that 'i' is a global variable for example, so someone didnt put var i and just assigned a value, this is the kind of information that this bookmarklet is supposed to give.

Comment: Interesting, so you want to list the defaults globals, and check window for all it has, then what is not listed, you will console.log it. Is it a opensource project? can you give us the link for it?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/4635185

Comment: +1 nice Idea, might come in really handy to check for things global namespace polution

Comment: @GabrielGartz Can you give an example of a not built-in function that will return [object Function] ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As`window.Audio` has a different `toString` method than `Object`
(`Audio.toString === Object.toString //false`)
,any other `function`s or `Object`s `toString` Method may be overwritten and could return `[object Function]`

Now, people don't run around and overwrite their functions `toString` method.So you might go really well with this approach.
But may it for debugging reasons or something else, someone may decide to do this.

### Update:

A trivial ECMAScript 5's solution would be possible too ( *[Compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys#Compatibility)* )

```
(function () {
    var keys = Object.keys(window),
        r = {};
    for (var i = 0, j; j = keys[i]; i++) {
        r[j] = window[j];
    }
    console.dir(r);
})();
```

### Edit:

As you thankfully pointed out the last Answer didn't work right *(i don't know even what i was thinking)*

Anyway, another approach could be

- Create a new empty Iframe (about:blank)
- Get all `window` properties *The properties included from the beginning*
- Push all others into an Array

### [Example](http://jsbin.com/ajotid/1/edit)

```
function getNonNatives(window) {
var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
iframe.src = "about:blank";
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
var natives = iframe.contentWindow,nonnatives = {};
for(var prop in window)
  if(!natives[prop] && window[prop] !== null)
    nonnatives[prop] = window[prop];
document.body.removeChild(iframe);
  return nonnatives;
};
console.log(getNonNatives(window));
```

This way you wouldn't have to bother too if someone would override, an Objects/Functions `toString` method.

*I won't include the old code in this edit for readabilities sake*

### Comment

To Answer the question in the Comment what `!!~` does:

The `~` is a Bitwise NOT operator which inverts the Bits of its Operand.

So given this logic it can be used as a shorthand  with `indexOf` to check if it found anything,
as it returns `-1` if nothing is found else a positive number.

`~-1 == 0` and e.g `~4 == -5`

Then `!!` is used to convert it to a Boolean

`!!0 == false` and `!!-5 == true`

Basically its a shorthand for

`if( myString.indexOf("myValue") > -1)`

Comment: I have never seen the !!~ with indexOf, very nice.

Comment: Still, the answer is not complete. Consider window.StackExchange which is a regular Object, your code considers it as native.

Comment: What does `!!~` do? (Google won't return any results for "!!~")

Comment: @tomdemuyt Ohohoh, thx, what was i thinking when i wrote that, i'll think of another approach and update the answer asap.
@ DG I'll include an Explanation what it does

Comment: +1 and accepted, my code still checks for `window.hasOwnProperty(key)` as that will catch globals like `window.TEMPORARY`.